# Data Usage & Firebase Querying

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My question is in regards to data usage. I was thinking of implementing pagination to my app, but I feel as if I were to add it in, the data usage would be more than just regularly grabbing a snapshot; so my question is, are the following queries using the same amount of data? or is the one that is a query limited, using less data? By data I mean data being downloaded from firebase that would affect my pricing rates.

```
let dbReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
        let query = dbReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "display_name")
        query.queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            print(snap)

        }




let dbReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
            dbReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                print(snap)

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second operation **may** read less data.

Whether it does depends on two things:

1. The number of users in the database.

   1. If there are 5 or fewer users, the amount of data will be the same.
   2. If there are more than 5 users, the second fragment will read all of them, while the first may read only 5 (depending on the below).
2. Whether you've [defined an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `display_name`.

   1. If you defined an index, the first snippet will read only 5 items from the server.
   2. If you didn't define an index, both operations will download the same amount of data and the first snippet will filter the data client-side.

Comment: What if there are more than 5 users? Also could you elaborate on what you mean by defining an index and how that relates to data consumption?

Comment: Updated my answer